# Environment doesn't have content type hub timer job

Tags: content-type-hub

I got one Sharepoint 2010 enterprise environment from my Admin team and I am trying to configure Content Type Hub on it.

I have successfully configured Content Type hub with managed metadata but when I go to Timer Job definitions, I didn't find "Content Type Hub Timer Job" there however, I do have Content Type Subscriber job for each web application

What could be possible cause and solution for this issue ? How would get back "Content Type Hub" timer job

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following steps:

```
   Go to your Content Type Hub top-level site.
    Open Site Settings.
    Open the Site Collection Features page.
    Make sure the Content Type Syndication Hub feature is Enabled
```

Comment: Yes..It is activated. Even I tried deactivate and activate same feature also